# How can I see the permissions of a directory with `ls`?

Tags: linux, directory

I want to see similar output like:

```
ls -l /etc/php5/php.ini
```

Which would give me:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 40344 Jun 14 14:33 /etc/php5/php.ini
```

Except the file in question is a directory, and doing `ls -l` on it would list it's contents.

How can I have it give me that permissions/info for a directory, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ls -ld` for directories. Quoting from the man page:

> -d, --directory
>      list directory entries instead of contents, and do not dereference symbolic links

Answer (score 5):

Use `stat dirname` - just to be different!

Comment: Here's another one just to be different: `find /path/to/parent/dir -maxdepth 1 -type d -name dirname -ls`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-d` option:

```
ls -ld dirname
```

Answer (score 1):

use the d flag

```
ls -ld directory_name
```